# The modeling entities for web is different for the Android? Can I use the same diagram classes for the both?

Tags: android, orm, web

I'm working on a project that has two modules: a web and an application for Android. Can I use the same class diagram for the two modules?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please provide as much detail as possible about the web module, and what it might share in common with the Android application.  Android is all Java mobile client. How about the web part?

Comment: In general I would think that you probably would not be able to reuse the class diagram.  What are you planning to do with the class diagram?

Comment: Also are these modules eclipse projects?  Android is usually an eclipse project but not always. You probably need to import all projects into eclipse for starters.

Comment: The two modules would do the same tasks. Treat the same types of data. The web module would also be in Java. The question is whether this same modeling classes works for Android.

Comment: ok butt if the classes depend on any of the Android classes it won't work.  You need to see if there area any dependencies on the Android SDK like for example Content Resolver.

Comment: please check as answered so I get points! Are you in Sao Paolo?  Send me your email siliconbeachmobile at gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same class diagram provided that it does not have dependencies on either Android SDK or Libraries that are specific to the web module.  Otherwise you would be better off with separate class diagrams/models.